# Associative Arrays in Android or Java

Tags: android, arrays, associative-array

Is it possible to do associative arrays in Android? Are there libraries that enable this, if not natively?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122913/java-associative-array

Comment: Yes, the other thread was already there, but it's for Java. I was hoping there might be an associative array support in Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android supports the [Java Collections Framework](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html). You can use a `Map` object for associative storage and retrieval. The Java language does not support subscripting notation for associative access; you need to use method calls (`get`, `put`, etc.) for that.

Comment: Is it possible to write associate array in Android arrays.xml file?

Comment: @twlkyao - Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196015/android-is-it-possible-to-define-a-map-in-an-xml-file/10196618#10196618).