# Android Is it possible to define a map in an XML file?

Tags: android, xml, dictionary, resources

I was trying to define a static hash table that makes use of resources, but I got stonewalled by the impossibility of accessing resources statically.
Then I realized that the best of all places to define a static map is in the resources files themselves.
How can I define a map in  XML?
I believe that if possible it should be similar to the Listpreference mechanism, with entries and entries-values.

Comment: check this out..http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android?dm_switcher=true

Comment: Can you please give us an example what would you like to do exactly?

Comment: Blehi, I want to have a static map that I can access many time from any class. I would like, ideally, to look like this:

<map name="food">
   <item key="@string/apple" value="12"/>
   <item key="@string/banana" value="10"/>
   <item key="@string/soup" value="5"/>
</map>

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> How can I define a map in XML?

```
<thisIsMyMap>
  <entry key="foo">bar</entry>
  <entry key="goo">baz</entry>
  <!-- as many more as your heart desires -->
</thisIsMyMap>
```

Put this in `res/xml/`, and load it using `getResources().getXml()`. Walk the events to build up a `HashMap<String, String>`.

Comment: This is not what I need. Actually, it is, the table part in XML. But I cannot use getResources() in the static context where I want to build the hash map.

Comment: @ilomambo: Initialize your hash map in `onCreate()` of a custom `Application` subclass. That is called after any `ContentProviders` you have are created, but before anything else of your app will run. `Application` is a `Context` and should work for parsing this XML.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your answer, I will use it. I need to save a HashMap as an XML file, How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: This example is incomplete. Writing the XML is easy, writing the parser is slow and a pain. See my example below for a much simpler solution.

Comment: @vangorra the answer is correct and a Map like this is much easier to maintain than two arrays if it becomes long. To make it easier to implement this solution I have added a simple parser for this purpose below

Comment: @CommonsWare can you please tell me how to extract from xml to hashmap

Comment: Is it possible to make an array as the value?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: You can make XML be as complicated as you wish.

Comment: @CommonsWare How do I put an array of strings inside the value? Currently what I did is put json string inside, which is weird...

Comment: @androiddeveloper: `<entry key="foo"><item>bar</item><item>baz</item><item>goo</item></entry>`. Or `<entry key="foo"><item value="bar"/><item value="baz"/><item value="goo"/></entry>`. Or `<entry key="foo"><array><item>bar</item><item>baz</item><item>goo</item></array></entry>`. Or whatever. XML can definitely handle collections of elements that you, in Java, elect to model as an array.

Comment: @CommonsWare All are correct, yes, but what about the parser of Android? In my case, I need to give the xml file as parameter to FirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults() method : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig#public-methods . Do you really think it can handle them all the same way? I don't even know if it supports arrays, since its getters don't seem to support getting an array list... :(

Comment: @androiddeveloper: "what about the parser of Android?" -- Android has three XML parsers. All can parse that XML. "I need to give the xml file as parameter..." -- Firebase should document what that XML resource needs to look like. Neither you nor I get a vote as to what it should look like. And whether *Firebase* handles arrays is a very separate matter than whether *XML* handles arrays.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, sadly I don't see it in the docs, so I think it's not supported. Thank you and have +1s .

Answer (score 42):

A simpler option would be to use two arrays. This has the benefit of not iterating the XML file again, uses less code, and is more straightforward to use arrays of different types.

```xml
<string-array name="myvariablename_keys">
   <item>key1</item>
   <item>key1</item>
</string-array>


<string-array name="myvariablename_values">
   <item>value1</item>
   <item>value2</item>
</string-array>
```

Then your java code would look like this:

```java
String[] keys = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myvariablename_keys);
String[] values = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myvariablename_values);
LinkedHashMap<String,String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(keys.length, values.length); ++i) {
   map.put(keys[i], values[i]);
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution, used internally in AOSP for many situations.  Be careful because it is only appropriate when the the map is small enough to edit without causing alignment problems, and when you will not face localization issues.  For example, if you intend to localize only the values, not the keys, this would become a maintenance nightmare if you need to add a new key. But there are plenty of cases where this is the best way to go.

Comment: @BrentK. This is why you should always reference to a string resource, and not a hard coded string

Comment: For Kotlin you can use this to create the map from the arrays, `keys.zip(values).toMap()`.

Answer (score 12):

You can always embed Json inside your `strings.xml` file:

res/values/strings.xml

```
<string name="my_map">{"F":"FOO","B":"BAR"}</string>
```

And inside your Activity, you can build your Map in the `onStart` method:

```
private HashMap<String, String> myMap;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    myMap = new Gson().fromJson(getString(R.string.my_map), new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>(){}.getType());
}
```

This code needs Google Gson API to work. You can do it using the built-in Json API in the Android SDK.

And As for accessing the Map statically, you can create a static method:

```
private static HashMap<String, String> method(Context context) {
    HashMap<String, String> myMap = new Gson().fromJson(context.getString(R.string.serve_times), new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>(){}.getType());
    return myMap;
}
```

Comment: in this case it's better to save as json file in assets folder!

Answer (score 6):

The correct answer was mentioned by CommonsWare above, but as XML-parsing is not so simple, as following a simple parser for this purpose:

```
public static Map<String, String> getHashMapResource(Context context, int hashMapResId) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    XmlResourceParser parser = context.getResources().getXml(hashMapResId);

    String key = null, value = null;

    try {
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                if (parser.getName().equals("entry")) {
                    key = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "key");

                    if (null == key) {
                        parser.close();
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                if (parser.getName().equals("entry")) {
                    map.put(key, value);
                    key = null;
                    value = null;
                }
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                if (null != key) {
                    value = parser.getText();
                }
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: as I wrote the correct answer was mentioned by Commonsware, it was only an addition. I thought it is not usefull to copy the answer of Commonsware again in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Android often works with `DefaultsXmlParser.getDefaultsFromXml()` which parse next syntax:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<defaults>
    <entry>
        <key>api_url</key>
        <value>https://</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <key>some_feature_flag</key>
        <value>true</value>
    </entry>
</defaults>
```

And read map:

```
val map = DefaultsXmlParser.getDefaultsFromXml(this, R.xml.my_map)
```