# Java code equivalent to following php code

Tags: java, php

What could be the java equivalent code for following php syntax:

```
   $newPerson = array(
        'firstname'  => 'First',
        'lastname'   => 'Last',
        'email'      => 'test@example.com',
    );
```

I think here `firstname` is index of array and `First` is value at that index.How can I define such an array in java?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122913/java-associative-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map<String, String> newPerson = new HashMap<String, String>()
{{
    put("firstname", "First");
    put("lastname", "Last");
    put("email", "test@example.com");
}};
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the closest you'll come is a map:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("firstname", "First");
map.put("lastname", "Last");
map.put("email", "test@example.com");
```

EDIT: If you want to preserve insertion order (i.e. you need to know that `firstname` was added before `lastname`) then you might want to use `LinkedHashMap` instead.

Comment: May be a LinkedHashMap<String, String> is even more closer?

Comment: @Narendra: Possibly. It depends on whether the order is preserved in a PHP - I don't know. Will edit.

Comment: Yes this http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php says array is a  ordered map.

Comment: @Narendra: Right, thanks. Have left it as "If you want" as the OP may not be interested in that.

Answer (score 2):

`newPerson` would be a java hash map (`java.util.HashMap<String,String>`) and you would explicitly insert by using `put`

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<String, String> newPerson = new HashMap<String, String>();
newPerson.put("firstname", "First");
newPerson.put("lastname", "Last");
newPerson.put("email", "test@example.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also use `SortedMap` to store value with user-define index name in sorted order
here is sample code to do this
define a `SortedMap` with:

`SortedMap<String, String>newPerson = new TreeMap<String, String>();`

to put value in shorted-map used:
`newPerson.put("firstname", "First");`

and to get this value :
`newPerson.get(""firstname");`