# Java: Find word in string and edit words after the word

Tags: java, string, swing

For example I have a String like this:

```
String myString = "Money = 10
                   Arrows = 4"
```

I want to edit the arrows, so I have to find the word "Arrow" in the String and edit the number "4". Any idea how to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: use the `.contains()` method, i.e. `if (myString.contains("Arrow"))`

Comment: you could use regex with a positive lookahead in order to replace the value. on the other side, having multiple different logical values and keys in a single variable isn´t the best idea. Before trying to find the value i´d reconsider the current implementation

Comment: try using `Hashmaps` instead of having `String` to do such things.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit a value easily based on something else in the program, you can make it so the number is a variable instead. Judging by the code as well, you want there to be a new line, currently it's not doing that since you need to use `"\n"`

So the code should look like:

```
int arrows = 4;

String myString = "Money = 10" + "\n" + "Arrows = " + arrows;
```

If you then change the value of the integer `arrows` before declaring the string it will be different.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use java that much but if you need to find out is something is a letter you can use

```
  System.out.println(Character.isLetter('c'));
  System.out.println(Character.isLetter('5'));
```

And since your data is in a `string` you can loop trough it like trough an array, as far as I remember.

```
for(int i =0; i < yourStringName.length; i++)
```

But I must agree with @jack jay.
So here is a helpful post [Java associative-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122913/java-associative-array)