# Java HashMap of HashMap vs HashMap of String

Tags: java, perl, data-structures

I am new to Java and i am currently rewriting a Perl code in Java.
In Perl i have a Hash of Hash like

```
$hashref->{index1}->{index2}->{index3} = $value;
```

In this i store the index1 , index2 , and index3 in 3 separate hashes along with above hash.
Also Index1 and index2 are of type long and index3 is String.

Now i want to rewrite the similar stuff in Java.
So i came up with 2 ways

```
1)HashMap<Long, HashMap<Long ,HashMap<String,String> >>
2)HashMap<String, String> //In this approach i concatenate index1,index2 and index3 using _ and make a single string
```

I want to know which way will be efficient as max of 100 keys for index1, 300 keys for index2 and 700 keys for index3 is possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java equivalent of Perl's hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769111/java-equivalent-of-perls-hash)

Comment: Please note that your first code snipped is definitely NOT compilable Perl code :)

Comment: refer DVK link... you will get what you want...

Comment: Actually, upon re-reading, I think he meant to ask a SLIGHTLY different question - should a 3level HashMap be used, or 1-level. I'll answer that.

Comment: The difference in efficiency will be fairly minimal; it depends on your access pattern(s). Nested hashes makes more sense, though, particularly if you need direct access (i.e., without looping over keys to find matches) to particular sub-keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's discuss #2

- It doesn't work 100% of the time due to possible ambiguity if the index strings can contain the separator character ("_"):

  E.g. consider 3 sets of indexes: ("12", "13_13" and "14") and ("12_13", "13" and "14"). They both produce the same concatenated key.
- It doesn't allow straightforward processing of the 2-d and 3-d level hashes as data structures **easily**.

  E.g. you can not easily do Java equivalent of "`keys %{$hash->{index1}}`" - find all the keys for a hash of second level stored under index1. It's doable, but much harder. Or "`delete $hash->{index1}`".

If these 2 considerations don't bother you, using a concatenated key for 1-level HashMap is fine.

If they do, you need to do #1 - a fairly robust implementation was posted on SO previously: 
" [Java equivalent of Perl's hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769111/java-equivalent-of-perls-hash/4770421#4770421) " . Please note that such implementation is NOT trivial, and therefore your alternate approach of concatenated 1 level of indexes is a very good alternative.

Comment: I suspect that option 2 also could have problems if two maps with the same entries had different iteration order.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - if he wants a Perl hash equivalent, I don't think he cares about iteration order at all. Good point though

Comment: I wouldn't say *much* harder, you'd need to iterate over all the keys and match a given pattern; easy enough if you use different chars between the keys. I'd still use nested hashes, though.

Comment: @DVK ...I went through Java Equivalent of Perl's Hash and to some extent i am clear with usage. Also please comment which will be faster/efficient my first approach or the second approach?

Comment: @Raghuram faster what? Faster to execute or faster from coding perspective?

Comment: @Raghuram - depends on your data and access pattrens. Why don't you try both methods and benchmark? Most likely, both are relatively similar performance wise, with 1-level being marginally faster (less HashMap mechanics to deal with)